# Xamarin Media Control Element

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I have a media control element in my content page, I would like to pause the video right before it ends, which is around 4 and a half seconds. I am struggling to figure this out.

```
    <xct:MediaElement
            x:Name="splash"
            Aspect="Fill"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            ShowsPlaybackControls="False"
            Source="ms-appx:///splash.mp4"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Is the actual element in my XAML and I have tried;

```
    System.TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 4);

            if (splash.Position == duration)
            {
                splash.Pause();
                DisplayAlert("Hey", duration.ToString(), "Ok");
            }
```

Comment: where are you executing that code?  Unless you have it in a loop it will only run once and unless it happens to execute **exactly** at 4s it will not work.  A better approach would be to use a Timer to fire after 4s

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason said, you could use a timer. The code below is a sample about pausing the video after 10 seconds.

Xaml:

```
  <xct:MediaElement Aspect="Fill"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"        MediaOpened="splash_MediaOpened"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="splash" Source="https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/5d93/a1eab4bf-3288-4faf-81c4-294402a85d93/XamarinShow_mid.mp4"
          ShowsPlaybackControls="True" />
```

Code behind:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        splash.Pause();
    }

    private void splash_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
    }
```